# Python jedi language server running after closing IDE

Tags: python, linux, visual-studio-code

I have a problem with one of the build-in python extensions.
After closing Visual Studio Code a new task starts, which takes up a considerable amount of processing power.

[image: Htop view]

I have confirmed it to be related with the python vscode extension, as the problem does not occur after I uninstall it.
According to the info found in the official vscode-python repository it is a [recent feature](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/releases/tag/2021.2.576481509).

Has someone encountered a similar problem or could someone give me a hint on how to further inspect this problem ?

Comment: What problem does this cause?

Comment: @mmp97 -When using python in VS Code, it needs to use python language service (the default is'Jedi') to support many services, you could refer to [this document](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/language-server-extension-guide).

Comment: @TimRoberts As i mentioned it takes a considerable amount of processing power. Over 30% usage on all cores makes the machine noticeably slower.

Comment: @JillCheng Thanks, will check it out. 
The core of the problem is that it is not using VS Code, as i mentioned: "Afterr closing Visual Studio Code a new task starts". The jedi language server only starts AFTER i close the IDE and starts to occupy my resources

Comment: @mmp97 -You could refer to the content of this link to set _"python.experiments.optOutFrom": ["pythonJediLSP"]_ in settings: [Rogue Python Processes with High CPU Consumption](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15586)